# Android NFC Components - DAL,LLC,OSAL, HCI and LIBNFC?

Tags: android, nfc

Hi All NFC enthusiasts, 
I am trying to understand the code for formatting a particular type of a NFC card , before that I was trying to gothrough the code for libnfc-nxp in the Android source code/external/linbfc-nxp folder.

Can any one give me 30000 ft overview of  NFC Components - DAL,LLC,OSAL, HCI and LIBNFC ?
What and why they are used.
rgds,
softy

Comment: You might want to state your particular problem. SO is a basically Q&A site, and too suitable for discussing general architectural issues. Generally, you shouldn't be concerned with the low level code if you just wan t a format card, so what are you trying to do and with what card?

Comment: If you just want to format a tag, name the tag-type, and we might be able to tell you where the documentation is. No need to dig into libnfc for that.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck its a ISO15693 complinat card.DO I need to add sepearte format/read/write methods for it or Android has it already .But that will nto be a motive for me to prevent myself for not looking into the libnfc  code.Isnt it?